# Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 111, in client.run(my_secret)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

There is this Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 112, in client.run(my_secret) and I'm trying to figure it out what the problem could be but I don't have a clue. Someone who could maybe help? (don't mind my starter_encouragements) I just can't think of anything This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 111, in <module>
    client.run(my_secret)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />
<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>
<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 73377d005b0c2ca7 &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-07-31 15:50:11 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>
      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>
          
      </section>
      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>
      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">73377d005b0c2ca7</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.136.154.72</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->
    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->
  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>
<script>(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'73377d005b0c2ca7',m:'_6R_xxsqH64VrlAWz0nGIVlnG6ylIN9m5H6r06gIOak-1659282611-0-AX0dswP/of2fyIIHz1muF0bremzuCD2OYnlZP0on2JAwB/5jC0K58aCNrK/tW8pdXnvaA+5g9DsTWXpx2mjgr8JaWB5Ij6/krepUwf7wYt5kv1LBknVlFLqv5keuIhSZSb7dM70TcZYmh10VeM5reng=',s:[0x80cd1e0c4e,0x5b9712f090],}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

And this is the code:

```
import discord
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db
from keep_alive import keep_alive


client = discord.Client()

sad_words = ["sad", "depressed", "unhappy", "angry", "miserable", "depressing", "traurig", "betrogen", "betrügt", "depressed", "down", "ehrenlos", "ehrenloser", "horny", "im gay", "homosexual", "skase", ":(", "malaka", "gamo", "gamw", "pateras sou", "mana sou", "mama sou", "ante kai"]

starter_encouragements = [
  "Cheer up!",
  "Hang in there.",
  "You are a great person /Malaka!",
  "You are the best malaka on the server",
  "Look into your future and never look back",
  "stfu just another fatherless child",
  "stop existing",
  "Do a flip from a 90 meter tall building"
]

if "responding" not in db.keys():
  db["responding"] = True

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(quote)

def update_encouragements(encouraging_message):
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    encouragements.append(encouraging_message)
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements
  else:
    db["encouragements"] = [encouraging_message]

def delete_encouragment(index):
  encouragements = db["encouragements"]
  if len(encouragements) > index:
    del encouragements[index]
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements

def get_thoughts():
  response = requests.get("https://randomthingstodo.com/thoughts")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  thought = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(thought)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content

  if msg.startswith('$inspire'):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)

  if db["responding"]:
    options = starter_encouragements
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      options = options + db["encouragements"]

    if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
      await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))

  if msg.startswith("$new"):
    encouraging_message = msg.split("$new ",1)[1]
    update_encouragements(encouraging_message)
    await message.channel.send("New encouraging message added.")

  if msg.startswith("$del"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      index = int(msg.split("$del",1)[1])
      delete_encouragment(index)
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)

  if msg.startswith("$list"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)

  if msg.startswith("$responding"):
    value = msg.split("$responding ",1)[1]

    if value.lower() == "true":
      db["responding"] = True
      await message.channel.send("Responding is on.")
    else:
      db["responding"] = False
      await message.channel.send("Responding is off.")

keep_alive()

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: The problem is "access denied".

Comment: `discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests` You're spamming the website and they decided they don't want to talk to you anymore.

Comment: "Too Many Requests"

Comment: Haha I can't stop laughing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by too many requests being sent to discord (commonly referred to as 'api abuse'). Discord then, effectively, bans the IP responsible for sending these requests.

**However**, in this case, it's because you are using [replit](https://replit.com/). Replit uses what we call "shared IP's" - effectively, your bot is on the same server as many other bots. Discord of course, can't see the difference - as far as Discord is concerned, all these bots on repl sharing the same IP are *the same thing*, and are therefore spamming the API, = ban.

Your temporary solution here is to type `kill 1` in repl's "shell". This will kill your session and often place you onto a new IP, therefore sidestepping the IP ban and restriction.

A more permanent solution is to fund your own hosting, either via a dedicated VPS or a local option (such as a raspberry pi), so that you aren't sharing your Bot amongst a horde of other peoples bots.

Sidenote: unrelated to your issue, but it appears you're using the non-async `requests` library. It's *very* important you stick with *async* libraries with discord bots! Otherwise your bot will stall whenever it has to use a non-async library. Instead of `requests`, use [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is giving error in the line of the token, u can just reset the token and i think this will solve the issue.
There was same error in my bot as well, and i changed the token it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Running in the shell

```
pip install --upgrade discord.py
```

and then it advised to also run

```
/opt/virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip'
```

It helped me.